# Update BitmapImage every second flickers

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage

I am trying to update an image by setting the source property every second, this works however causes a flicker when updated.

```
CurrentAlbumArt = new BitmapImage();
CurrentAlbumArt.BeginInit();
CurrentAlbumArt.UriSource = new Uri((currentDevice as AUDIO).AlbumArt);
CurrentAlbumArt.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
CurrentAlbumArt.EndInit();
```

If I don't set `IgnoreImageCache`, the image does not update thus no flickering either.

Is there a way around this caveat?

Cheers.

Comment: You may first download the image buffer completely, then create a MemoryStream from that buffer and finally create a new BitmapImage and assign its `StreamSource` property.

Comment: I've tried doing that using a BmpBitmapEncoder however it causes the same flickering to happen.

Comment: Why encoder? You want to decode an image. I'll provide some example code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code snippet downloads the whole image buffer *before* setting the Image's `Source` property to a new BitmapImage. This should eliminate any flicker.

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
var url = ((currentDevice as AUDIO).AlbumArt;
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(webClient.DownloadData(url)))
{
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
    bitmap.EndInit();
}

image.Source = bitmap;
```

If the download takes some time, it would make sense to run it in a separate thread. You would then have to take care for proper cross-thread access by also calling `Freeze` on the BitmapImage and assigning `Source` in the Dispatcher.

```
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(webClient.DownloadData(url)))
{
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
    bitmap.EndInit();
}

bitmap.Freeze();
image.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => image.Source = bitmap));
```

Comment: Thanks Clemens, didn't even think about using WebClient. Cheers.